# Differences between ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) vs ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Why should I choose `ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)` instead of `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)`?

I'm talking about options 1 and 3 in the options below, what will be the difference?
[image]

I saw the following question, but I still don't understand what is the difference between option 1 and 3:
[Visual Studio 2015 Web Application .NET Core vs .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627234/visual-studio-2015-web-application-net-core-vs-net-framework)

Comment: Please use the search before asking a question, it's been answered before. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452041/difference-between-using-the-asp-net-core-web-application-net-core-with-net46?rq=1

Comment: @Tseng This is not a duplicate. The question is asking about the difference between options #1 and #3. The other questions do not address that.

Comment: I read those links, but still I'm not sure why should one choose option 3 on top of 1...

Comment: Or even, why do Microsoft give us option 1 at all?

Comment: Option 1 is an ASP.NET 4 website running on the full .NET Framework. Option 2 is an ASP.NET Core website running on .NET Core. Option 3 is an ASP.NET Core website running on .NET Core. If you don't know what any of those are, then go do some research. There's TONS of information about each of these available.

Comment: @Mason You are saying that options 2) and 3) are equal?

Comment: @RobertGoldwein. No, not at all. Previous comment should have said Option 3 is ASP.NET Core running on *the full .NET Framework*

Answer (score 55, accepted):

- Option 1 - ASP.NET Web Application
- Option 3 - ASP.NET Core Web Application

Although both project templates use Full .Net Framework, ***Option 1*** is for creating projects using ***legacy version of ASP.NET MVC*** in which we can use Global.asax.

***Option 3*** is totally new concept in which *wwwroot* folder, using *task runners* and everything is through *OWIN middleware*.

A lot of organization and companies are not ready to jump into new project template yet. *I believe Option 1 is there for backward compatibility.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) is missing in VS2017. Is it intended or do I have to install anything?